# Invalid Uri: invalid port specified C#

Tags: c#, ftp, uri, port

I recently created a FTP Server locally with FileZilla Server. With the admin port 14147 by default. Then with the FileZilla Client I got connected with no problems.

When I try to connect by chrome or ie with

```
ftp://(ip)
```

or

```
ftp://(full machine name)
```

or

```
ftp://(user:password)@(machine).
```

Everything is ok.

My admin interface setting port is 14147.
My listing port by default is 21

No problems at all with Internet browsers even with telnet.

Now I created an application in C# and when I use the Uri class

```
Uri target = new Uri(strUri);
```

I got an exception error: **Invalid Uri: invalid port specified**

I saved the ftp address in a database like this and I tried many variations but nothing happens:

```
ftp://user:password@FullMachineNameWithDomain
ftp://user:password@FullMachineNameWithDomain:21
ftp://user:password@FullMachineNameWithDomain:14147
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Username and password are not supposed to be part of the URL.
You should pass them separately as credentials when you're using something like FtpWebRequest class. E.g.

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I think that it's not true at all. There was a ftp address before just like mine and it worked very well. I decided to create my own FTP Server locally to perform some test to avoid the Security Rights! Maybe my problem is the configuration of my FTP Server.

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm using the request.Credentials. What I meant is that the URI constructor must accept the address. I found my problem. My password was encrypted but it was no ok. Thanks.